# Can I assign an alternative openId to my careers account?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, openid

Is there any way to do this?  Am I missing something, or is it just not there?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, we were trying to keep careers a bit simpler.

Is there a need for more than one?

Comment: I accidentally picked Google OpenID for my Careers one, when I use livejournal for every other one. It's a 'meh' answer; but I just want to be sure it's properly associated.

Comment: Yeah, I have a similar issue where I have switched from Yahoo! (which I signed up to StackOverflow with) to Google. It's not massively important but having been able to add the Google one to my regular StackOverflow account, it would be nice to do the same on careers. There are just too many passwords and userids in the world and my poor brain can't cope... :-)